# Finding the sum of Arithmetico Geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

My textbook has defined the arithmetico geometric series as follows:

> "A series, each term of which is formed by multiplying the corresponding terms of an A.P and G.P is called the Arithmetico Geometric series."

I am interested to find the sum of this series up to n terms. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use MathJax effectively. Forgive me for my sloppiness.

Let the A.P be given by 
$a, a+d, a+2d, a+3d, ... , a+(n-1)d$

And let the G.P be given by
$b, br, br², br³, ... , br$^(n-1)

The Arithmetico Geometric series is then given by

$ab+ [a+d]br+ [a+2d]br²+...+[a+(n-1)d]br$^(n-1)

I was unable to find the formula for the sum of this series up to n terms. Even [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence) Wikipedia page only proves for a specific case of this series, as does my textbook. So, I set out to derive the formula myself, after having gotten a hint from the linked Wikipedia page. I have done it as follows:

[image: Derivation]

Is my method correct and have I arrived at the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything else is fine except this-

$$S_n-rS_n=ab+dbr+dbr^2+....+dbr^{n-1}-(abr^n+(n-1)dbr^{n})$$

$$S_n-rS_n=ab-abr^n-(n-1)dbr^n+dbr\frac{(1-r^{n-1})}{(1-r)^2}$$

You can always check whether you are correct or not by putting in some values for $a$, $d$, $b$, $r$ and $n$.

Comment: Oh, yes, silly mistake. Thanks anna :-)