# Average power of 2 in all even natural numbers

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, number-theory, arithmetic

Consider all even natural numbers.
Every 4th number has a power of 4 (or $2^2$)

Every 8th number has a power of 8 (or $2^3$)

Every 16th number has a power of 16 (or $2^4$)

What is the average number of power of 2 in any random even number?

Since every 2nd number has a power of 2,and every 4th number is a power of 4 and so on

$\left(2 \times \dfrac{1}{2}\right) + \left(4 \times \dfrac{1}{4}\right) +  \left(8 \times \dfrac{1}{8}\right) + \ldots$

This goes all the way to Infinity and hence the answer is $\infty$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A multiple of $4$ only has two powers of $2$ in its factorization and a multiple of $8$ only has three.  Your sum should therefore be 
$$\left(1 \times \dfrac{1}{2}\right) + \left(2 \times \dfrac{1}{4}\right) +  \left(3 \times \dfrac{1}{8}\right) + \ldots=2$$
because half the evens have exactly one factor of two, one quarter have exactly two factors of two and so on.  Although it you can't pick a random natural number, this makes sense as the limit of the average number of factors of two in the even numbers up to $n$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: thanks a lot.I wonder how is the sum 2?the 1st 2 add upto to 1....not sure how to add rest,unable to use GP formula directly

Comment: It is an [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence).  This particular one is solved on this site.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751934/question-regarding-arithmetico-geometric-sequences) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926013/finding-the-sum-of-arithmetico-geometric-series).  You can search for arithmetico-geometric

Answer (score 1):

I think you are double counting the multiples of $4$ since half of them have been counted as multiples of $2$. That multiple counting continues.

I think the sum (corrected as I suggest) for the power of $2$ dividing a "random integer", is 
$$
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots
$$
which sums to $1$. That makes sense for the average power of $2$.

The result for a random even integer would be $2$.

I put "random integer" in quotes since defining a 
"random integer" is a little subtle.

Comment: A "little subtle" ... like trisecting the angle. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes Not quite. I think you can make sense of that expected value as a limit. I didn't want to spend the time.

Comment: Indeed... I meant that picking a uniform distribution on the integers might be a little problematic.